# Mackie pro recording and only showing audio from one input

Tags: audio-recording

So I have a Mackie ProFX16v3 and when I try to record from that into my computer via USB only the first input on the board actually sends to my PC. I tried moving that cable to other channels and nothing. I even adjusted my input on reaper to the corresponding channels and nothing.

How can I get it to record or even input from the other channels?

Answer (score 1):

The USB output from the mixer is pre-main fader so should deliver 2x4 24bit 192kHz stereo signal to the computer, according to the [User Manual](https://mackie.com/sites/default/files/PRODUCT%20RESOURCES/MANUALS/Owners_Manuals/ProFXv3_OM.pdf).

Also, read the manual and check all of the following:

- Line/Hi-Z switch
- Set all knobs at midpoint
- FX switches
- Mute switches
- Solo switches
- Channel assignment switches